# Append JSON array with another item using Python

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql

I recently migrated to Python and cannot solve quite simple problem (using Django). A model has JSON field (PostgreSQL), lets say, for example, fruits. When updating an instance, I do it like this:

```
model.fruits = {"id": 1, "name": "apple"}
model.save()
```

When editing a model, I would like to add another fruit (append), so the result would have few JSON items, and model.fruits would return value like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "apple"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "banana"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "orange"
    },
]
```

I have tried to search for solutions, but it seems like append function for this dictionary overwrites the values, not appends them. What would be a fast way to append items to this JSON field in database? Maybe there is a library for fast work-around?

Answer (score 2):

`model.fruits = {"id": 1, "name": "apple"}`* defines a dictionary, you cannot *append* to a dictionary, you can add keys to it

You can append elements into a JSON array though, e.g. if `model.fruits` was an array (or a list, as it is called in Python), e.g.

`model.fruits = [{"id": 1, "name": "apple"},]`

which defines an array with 1 element in it, then you can append to it

`model.fruits.append({"id": 2, "name": "banana"})`

Some references:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

<sub>* To be honest it doesn't make sense to name something in the plural like `fruits` to hold a single object, should be a container, like a list</sub>

Answer (score -1):

In Django, you should make a new model called Fruit.

```
class Fruit(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
```

in your main model you should have a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

```
fruits = models.ManyToManyField(Fruit, blank=True, related_name='model')
```

This way you would be able to add some more fields in future do filtering and whole other things.

To add a fruit to model object

```
obj.fruits.add(1, 2)  # where 1 and 2 are id's  of fruits to add
```